# Rotate textured mesh object or rotate camera around 3D textured object in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to load a .obj file corresponding to a textured mesh, rotate it in different angles and take a snapshot of it, in Python.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which libraries do you use?

Comment: I've tried mlab (mayavi2) but just managed to rotate a newly created 3D object, not an imported (.obj file) textured mesh. Thanks